# Service Odoo 11

Tags: python, service, odoo

I wonder:

When I run the command systemctl status odoo11, here is what I get in image:

While I suppose there must be only one service launched in CGroup.
However, it breaks me some trouble of installations or spot work in my Odoo11
[image]

Can you help me ? I block thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`Odoo` service can be setup as multi-worker process in which the main service process starts multiple process as `worker`. If you check the `workers` value in the `/opt/odoo11/config.ini` you can find out how many workers you have currently setup for your `Odoo` service.